# Insert Statement Not Inserting With Correct Auto Incremental

Tags: mysql, vb.net, insert

For example, I have the 3 rows currently in the table with a primary key of 0, 1 and 3. I want it to fill the gap, so the next insert statement should take the primary key of 2. However, it is not doing that.

```vb
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    Dim msg As String = ""

    If Validate.CheckAddress(txtAddress.Text) And _
       Validate.CheckEmailAddress(txtEmailAddress.Text) And _
       Validate.CheckPhoneNumber(txtPhoneNumber.Text) And _
       Validate.CheckPostcode(txtPostcode.Text) Then

        MsgBox("correct validation")

        Dim Admin As Integer = 0
        Dim Query As String

        If chkAdmin.Checked Then
            Admin = 1
        Else
            Admin = 0
        End If

        If Not frmLogin.User.DoesUserExist(CInt(lblUserIDValue.Text)) Then  'if user doesnt exist
            Query = "INSERT INTO tbluser (Admin, UserForename, UserSurname, Username, Password, UserPhoneNumber, UserAddress, UserPostcode, UserEmailAddress) VALUES (@admin, @forename, @surname, @username, @password, @phonenumber, @address, @postcode, @emailaddress)"
            MsgBox("we are inserting")
        Else
            Query = "UPDATE tbluser SET Admin=@admin, UserForename=@forename, UserSurname=@surname, Username=@username, UserAddress=@address, UserPostcode=@postcode, UserEmailAddress=@emailaddress WHERE UserID=@userID"
            MsgBox("we are updating")
        End If

        Using Conn As New MySqlConnection(MySQL.ConnectionDetails)
            Using Comm As New MySqlCommand()
                With Comm
                    .Connection = Conn
                    .CommandText = Query
                    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@admin", Admin)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@forename", txtForename.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@surname", txtSurname.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", (txtForename.Text + txtSurname.Text.First + txtPhoneNumber.Text.Last.ToString)) 'firstname + first letter of surname + last number of phone number
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", "password")
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@phonenumber", txtPhoneNumber.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", txtAddress.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@postcode", txtPostcode.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailaddress", txtEmailAddress.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@userID", CInt(lblUserIDValue.Text))
                End With
                Try
                    Conn.Open()
                    If Comm.ExecuteNonQuery() Then
                        MsgBox("Successfull ")
                        Me.Dispose()
                    End If
                Catch ex As MySqlException
                    msg += "MySQL Exception " & ex.GetBaseException.ToString
                End Try
            End Using
       End Using

   Else

       If (Validate.CheckAddress(txtAddress.Text) = False) Then
           msg += "Not a valid address " & Environment.NewLine
       End If
       If (Validate.CheckEmailAddress(txtEmailAddress.Text) = False) Then
           msg += "Not a valid email address " & Environment.NewLine
       End If
       If (Validate.CheckPhoneNumber(txtPhoneNumber.Text) = False) Then
           msg += "Not a valid phone number " & Environment.NewLine
       End If
       If (Validate.CheckPostcode(txtPostcode.Text) = False) Then
           msg += "Not a valid postcode "
       End If

    End If

    If (msg <> "") Then
        MessageBox.Show("The following problems were found: " & Environment.NewLine & msg, "User - Error(s)", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Primary Keys are meant to be unique, not sequential.  If you define the Id as an autoincrement the DB will create one for you (thats part of its job!)  Which means you do not specify it in SQL INSERTs

Comment: @Plutonix I have set the ID as an autoincrement

Comment: To solve your issue long term, you need to create subsystem in which you, periodically, off [production] hours will run a procedure, which will enumerate all your keys and write all the `gap` keys into separate table. Then, in your `Insert` logic, you will try to reserve one of the gap numbers and use it as PK while you will need to disable auto increment. When no gap numbers available, you will go with insert as usual. But why would you go all this troubling way? What you gonna gain? Is it worth it?

Comment: @T.S. Alright thank you for your input. I guess it's not worth doing then. I thought there would be an easy way to do it because I was doing something wrong. I originally wanted to do it for clarity but I guess I can live with it.

Comment: Ah... what clarity? Primary key is just an ID that provides referential integrity. It shouldn't be visible to anyone. Therefore, no need for clarity. And if you have 100M records? 43724179 - is it clear anyway? :o)

Comment: @T.S. I use the IDs to identify every record as it is a program for a business so the business can easily refer to something as an ID e.g. this customer has this ID or this product has this ID etc.

Comment: In this case this is NOT how you do it. If you want visible, useful ID that people can refer to... you still have regular auto number that is PK for your data. And add another column that is UNIQUE KEY, in which you can store business unique value, like `PROD12345` or `CUST34567`.

Comment: @T.S. Is it a big problem? It seems to be working well the way it is.

Comment: What happening now is that you're trying to solve an issue that has been solved long time ago and now everybody just uses that solution. Remember your original issue? - to make [lets say] new "Product#2" if this product was deleted one day. We just solved it. In DB you going to have some new ID but in your Product list that users see you going to have new Product#2. Makes sense?

Comment: @T.S. No I'm sorry that didn't make sense however I have decided to still use the primary key as the product identifier also.

Comment: It is definitely up to you **what you** use as product identifier. In real world, lets say appliance company, uses product identifiers way more sophisticated than just `1, 2 or 3456`. The product IDs they use are like `MDG6000W` - "Maytag Dryer Gas Model# White". But that is not the primary key in the DB. The primary key is just an integer, it is providing referential integrity. For example, Product-Order integrity. It is **Not** product identifier though!!!  Product ID is unique key that used for business. Primary keys are used for data integrity. You use one as 2 -your decision- bad design

Comment: Ah, good example. We have DB and table `Users`. It had columns `id, username, name, address...`.  `id` is the PK and when data inserted, it is inserted under `id`. But this is never shown on any screen. Screens show only `username`, which should be unique but generally - changeable.

Answer (score 0):

1. truncate your table using TRUNCATE TABLE table_name
2. Insert your rows in required sequence

Comment: then live with current IDs :P

Comment: @Man16 ***"I dont want to completely empty the table though"***, you could dump this data to a temp table/table variable then `TRUNCATE` the table and finally dump it all back...